# Vue JS Event bus data not working outside scope of event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-events

I am using event bus to show alert on update data.so whenever user update the data i want to show an alert showing **"Data is udpated"** so for that i am using event bus

here is `BlogEdit.vue` Component where i am firing event

```
app.$router.push('/', () => {
    vueBus.$emit('showAlertBox')
})
```

And In `BlogList.vue` I am listning for this event

```
data: function(){
    return {
        showalert: false,
    }
},
vueBus.$on('showAlertBox',(data) => {
    this.showalert = true;
    console.log(this.showalert); //Returns True
})
console.log(this.showalert); //Returns False
```

But the result is unexpected as it change back to false.

Why `this.showalert` changed to false ? So that cause to not showing alert box.

Since i am new to vue js i read the documenatation and other solutions but i cant figure out where am i going wrong with this.

Comment: Since there's no whole code I would limitly understand but,
Event listener better to be located in `onMounted` method. (if vue2, `mount`)

Comment: also tried by doing that. Let me know if any other code is needd to show @lan Chao